# Save Label and Stepper with UserDefaults (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a **Label** and **Stepper**.

How can I save them using  **UserDefaults**?

```
// Stepper
@IBOutlet weak var Stepr1: UIStepper!

// "MIN" Label
@IBOutlet weak var MAXLabel: UILabel!
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to store?

Comment: @Priya values ​​in the Label that will appear when pressing stepper

Comment: First get the text of your label and then save it the String text in the UserDefaults with the appropriate key.

Comment: What problem are you actually having? Do you know how to use UserDefaults at all? Do you know how to get the text from a label and a stepper's value? Please show some effort and clarify what part of this you actually need help with.

Comment: Yes, @rmaddy tell right. Please elaborate your issue more clearly.

Comment: @Jacky you need to save the value in the shortcut so that the next time you start, the saved value appears

Comment: Yes, Then you can use the code that has been written by @Priya

Comment: @Jacky No, do not use the code by Priya. It is not the correct code.

Comment: Can you please explain, What is mistake in @Priya's Code ? I want to know something new about UserDefault.

Comment: @Jacky Read my 1st comment below the answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try bellow code to store value in userdefaults

```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.setValue(lbl.text, forKey: "data")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

    //Access user defaults
    print(userDefaults.value(forKey: "data"))
```

Comment: This is not the proper code. Do not needlessly using key-value coding to save and retrieves values in UserDefaults. Please look at the documentation for UserDefaults. Use the proper methods listed. And this answer doesn't actually show the proper code to save and retrieve a UILabel and UIStepper.

Comment: On stepar's click event. @B2Fq

Comment: @B2Fq Do not use this code. It is not the correct code. Please look at the documentation for `UserDefaults` for the proper methods.